# Removing MenuBar in awt package in java

Tags: java, awt, menubar

Is there any way available to remove the menubar from window in java in awt package.
I have created menubar based on a condition and when the condition gets false,i want to remove it in awt package(not using swing class methods), but unable to find any method to do so.

I should be able to create/remove menubars more than once based on the condition.

I am shocked to fail to find any method to completely remove the menubar even at the documentation provided by Oracle, though methods exists to remove components from menubar.

IS it a loophole?Did they missed something?

Comment: If you don't want MenuBar to be visible then make it `disabled`.

Comment: @VishalK I can only disable components on menubar.

Comment: Try whiskeyspider solution..It would work..

Answer (score 0):

Try: `setMenuBar(null);`

From the documentation:

> mb - the menu bar being set. If this parameter is null then any existing menu bar on this frame is removed.